# Bash script for renaming files to consecutive numbers in multiple directories

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a catalogue structure like this:

```
AD
 -> AD01
   -> DSC123.jpg
   -> DSC124.jpg
 -> AD02
   -> DSC234.jpg
   -> DSC1455.jpg
 -> AD03
  ->...
 -> AD04
  ->...
 ->...
AE
 ->...
...
```

No I would like to run a script that will traverse whole tree and rename each folder files to be a consecutive numbers 01.jpg, 02.jpg... etc.

I found something like this to help with consecutive numbers:

```
find -name '*.jpg' | gawk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s %02d.jpg\n", $0, a++ }' | bash
```

but how do I make it run on all the folders recursively, throughout the tree (there are like 1000 of folders each with about 6-20 files).

Edit:
Result should look like this:

```
AD
 -> AD01
   -> 01.jpg
   -> 02.jpg
 -> AD02
   -> 01.jpg
   -> 02.jpg
 -> AD03
  ->...
 -> AD04
  ->...
 ->...
AE
 ->...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `bash` script,

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(find -type d \( ! -name '.*' \)) 
do 
  i=1; 
  for file in $(find "$dir" -name '*.png')
  do 
     a=$(printf "%02d" $i)
     new=${file%/*}
     echo "mv $file $new/$a.png"
     let i=i+1
  done 
done
```

It will list out the `mv` commands that is going to apply. See whether it is giving what you expected. Finally, replace the `echo` with `mv` command.

Comment: The nested `find` commands are rather pesky, if you have mutliple layers of directories you will rename the same files multiple times. The competing answer is less problematic (though it too should probably be fixed in a couple of places).

Answer (score 1):

Use find to find the directories then cd into each directory in turn and rename the files.

```
find /path/to/catalogue -type d -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob
  for dir in "$@" ; do
    ( cd "$dir" || exit
      files=( *[!0-9]*.jpg )
      for (( n = 0 ; n < "${#files[@]}" ; n++ )) ; do
        printf -v target '%02d.jpg' $(( n + 1 ))
        mv -- "${files[$n]}" "$target"
      done )
  done
' bash {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest one using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
cd AD/AD02
rename -n 'no strict; s@.*(?=\.)@sprintf "%0.2d", ++$x@e' *.jpg
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find . -name "*.jpg" -type f)
a=1
for i in $files; do
  dir=$(dirname "$i")
  new=$(printf "%04d" ${a}) 
  mv ${i} $dir/${new}.jpg
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast replay but this does not work correctly - it makes my files look like this : AD01/45.jpg, AD01/23.jpg, AD02/05.jpg etc.... they are consecutive but not within a directory but within a parent directory...

Comment: `AD01/45.jpg, AD01/23.jpg, AD02/05.jpg etc.... ` are within directory. not getting exactly what you mean. can you explain more.

Comment: Edited my question, please see if that helps understanding the goal.

Comment: So in each directory you want file name started with `01` right?

Comment: Capturing the output of `find` in a variable is problematic if you have file names which contain whitespace or shell metacharacters. Failing to quote the variables you loop over exacerbates the problem. Do not use this.